# Google App Engine Custom Admin Pages in the New Google Cloud Console

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm a Google App Engine user, and I got this message saying the old app engine console will be retired by the end of March.

However - as it seems, there is no place in the Google Cloud Console (which is supposed to be the only available console to manage App Engine projects) to access and use the custom admin pages used to manage the project.

Does anyone know what is up with that?

Thanks,

-Lior